# Вывод данных по составному ключу на yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, view

Есть таблица с составным ключом

```html
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `students_activities` (
  `description` text,
  `a_level` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`a_level`,`record_book_number`)
);
```

Как вывести все `a_level`, которые есть у определенного `id`? Я не совсем понимаю как yii работает с составным ключом.

Answer (score 1):

В твоем запросе в ключе используется несуществующее поле record_book_number.

```
PRIMARY KEY (`a_level`,`record_book_number`)
```

Работа с составным ключом в моделях ActiveRecord, осуществляется следующим образом. Метод findByPk принимает первым аргументом массив, где ключ имя поля составного ключа, а значением является значение этого поля:

```
StudentsActivities::model()->findByPk(array('a_level'=>1,'record_book_number'=>2));
```

Чтобы просто получить список записей соответствующие какому-то значению в пол(е,ях), можно воспользоваться методом findAllByAttributes

```
StudentsActivities::model()->findByPk(array('id'=>1));
```